# OpenSSO and tomcat

Tags: tomcat, opensso

I am new to opensso(openam). I want to protect my webapplications deployed in tomcat using SSO. I have basic questions to clarify.

1. What are the basic software components required to get my work done like tomcat,opensso.war etc...
2. How many policy agents i need to install and in which places.

I have gone through the document and i am not able to understand it clearly.

Thanks in advance. waiting for your replay..

James

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the OpenSSO (now OpenAM) server first. This includes an installation of Tomcat, if you have not installed it yet. Here is a good guide to [install OpenAM on Ubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHuUaFaTnXI). The installation is quite simple, just download the right `openam.war` File and copy it to the Tomcat webapps directory. The GUI Configurator will guide you through the rest of the basic configuration process.

Then you need a J2EE Policy Agent for a J2EE application, or a Web Policy Agent for a normal web server or a web app in a different language (Web agents protect resources on web and proxy servers while J2EE agents protect resources on application and portal servers, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19316-01/820-5816/ghscr/index.html)). ForgeRock offers a guide to [install a Web Policy Agent for Apache](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Web+Policy+Agent+for+Apache+2.2+Installation+Guide). You will need one Web Policy Agent for each Apache instance, because they are implemented as an Apache module.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try the steps at http://blogs.oracle.com/jespraha/entry/opensso_on_tomcat_5_5x and get back with any specific problem

```
Tomcat 5.5x & 6.0x 
----------------- 

These are the steps we used to successfully install OpenSSO b3 on Tomcat 5.5x & 6.0x. It should be the same for b4. 

- extract Tomcat package 
- copy webservices-api.jar from http://download.java.net/general/opensso/extlib/latest/opensso-sun-extlib.zip to /common/endorsed (in version 6, you have to create these two directories) 
- edit /bin/catalina.sh 
add -Xms256m -Xmx1024m to the start command (find sth like "elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then") 
Note: there are 2 parts, one with -security switch, the second without it, edit the second one 
- restart server 
(/bin/shutdown.sh, /bin/startup.sh) 
- copy opensso.war to /webapps 
- restart server 
- run configurator (host:port/opensso) 
- restart server 
<script type="text/javascript"> var sc_project=3055623; var sc_invisible=0; var sc_partition=33; var sc_security="2841646f"; </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter_xhtml.js"></script>
```